# Fragment error accessing the view

Tags: android

I am trying to use tabs and `PagerAdapter` to make a tab layout.

I have the following expression in my `Fragment`:

```
cpPrecTextView = (BootstrapLabel) getView().findViewById(R.id.cpPrec);
cpPrecTextView.setText(cpPrecTextView.getText() + cpPrec);
```

My app crashes with the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                      at com.pgoiv.pokemongoiv.TabFragment1.onCreateView(TabFragment1.java:45)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: tells you that `getView()` is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getView()` is returning null. I'm assuming you didn't inflate the container view properly for the `Fragment`. So inside your `onCreateView` you need to inflate the view first like this.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout and get the reference of the view 
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_tickets, container, false);

    // Now find any view inside that 
    cpPrecTextView = (BootstrapLabel) v.findViewById(R.id.cpPrec);
    cpPrecTextView.setText(cpPrecTextView.getText() + cpPrec);

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getView()` **returns null**

To solve this you should run all code that depends on a view in `onCreateView`. That way you will always have a reference to a view to use for finding other views.

You can consult the [Android Developers page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating) for more info about Fragment lifecycles!